# Troubleshooting `Buffer I/O error` on software-raid/md-device

Tags: linux, mdadm, io, smart, drive-failure

I've got a RAID-5 mdadm array that reliably causes `Buffer I/O error on dev md0, logical block 1598030208, async page read` to be written do `dmesg` when reading that block. Of course, the read also factually fails. This behavior is consistent across reboots, and it's always the same block.

I would like to understand where the error comes from. As I understand it, either one of the physical drives must cause trouble, or maybe the array is in an inconsistent state. Either way, I would like to know which it is, so that I can take further steps to try and fix the issue.

Unfortunately, `dmesg` does not give further hints at all.
I have looked at the `smart` parameters of all drives involved, but none raises suspicion. What else can I try to troubleshoot the array?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: As requested, the output of `mdadm --detail /dev/md0`:

```
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.0
  Creation Time : Sat Dec 28 03:50:47 2013
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 15621798144 (14898.11 GiB 15996.72 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3905449536 (3724.53 GiB 3999.18 GB)
   Raid Devices : 5
  Total Devices : 5
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Fri Dec 22 11:36:24 2017
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 5
Working Devices : 5
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

           Name : 0
           UUID : 01a3d3c1:6a5ac63d:0cc10dd0:f8e7a1c4
         Events : 2132931

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       5       8       51        0      active sync   /dev/sdd3
       1       8       83        1      active sync   /dev/sdf3
       4       8       35        2      active sync   /dev/sdc3
       7       8       67        3      active sync   /dev/sde3
       6       8        3        4      active sync   /dev/sda3
```

Update: I tried scrubbing the array by writing `repair` to `md/sync_action`. The process completed without any output to `dmesg` or signs of trouble in `/proc/mdstat`. However, reading from the array still fails at the same block as above, `1598030208`.

Update 2, for reference: I asked this question in the linux-raid mailing list: https://marc.info/?l=linux-raid&m=151486117529497&w=2

Comment: Whats the output of `mdadm --detail /dev/md0`?

Comment: @Deeh: Thanks for asking, I've edited my post to show the output.

Comment: Need more version numbers for your md package, kernel, distribution, and a general idea of what the workload is like.

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M: It's Debian 9 stretch, x86_64, kernel 4.9.30-2+deb9u5, mdadm v3.4, all software as distributed via the Debian repositories. The machine is used as a backup server, i.e. writes of a few TB at most, once a day, from one source only. This is also where I first encountered errors resulting in a read-only remount, which prompted me to run `fsck` on `md0` (unmounted), which consistently produces the error I described in my post.

Comment: Check your drives with `smartctl -a /dev/sda`. Add output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda`. Did anything change recently (drive replacement/repartitioning)?

Comment: @Deeh: Like I said, `smartctl` shows no suspicious signs (there have been a few errors in the past on one disk, but none that coincide with the errors I see now.) The disk partition layouts match. Regarding changes: these disks used to be part of a qnap-NAS that failed recently (SATA-controller or backplane). I migrated the disks, and am now able to mount the `ext4` filesystem normally. I'm just curious whether I can make `mdadm` tell me why it can't read that one block. Surely the raid subsystem must know why it can't produce the data?

Comment: Run `smartctl -t long /dev/sd*` on all your drives. One (or possibly more) will fail with an error. Then you will know which drive is failing and should be replaced.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Thanks, but that's not it in this case. I had three passes of badblocks work on each disk, followed by a smart self-test. Not a single error produced on any of the drives, neither for badblocks nor for smart.